# How to read Distinct Contacts with Contact Number and Name in android?

Tags: android

I want to read contact list ,I am able to get contact number but not name ,it is fetching different name . For Example: I have saved number as
    1) 8888888888 with name USER1
2) 9999999999 with name USER2
3) 4444444444 with name USER3 etc

It is displaying 8888888888 but name is USER3 in my app,
I want to read contact list in my app.Please Help me Out.

Thank You

Comment: please add some code !!!

Comment: Check out this repository. It contains retrieve, add, delete and update operations on ContactList. Repository: [ContentProvider](https://github.com/activesince93/ContentProvider)

Comment: I am not telling you to copy all the code. You can checkout that how this functionality works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<LocalContacts> localContactsObj = new ArrayList<LocalContacts>();

public void GetContacts(Context cntx) //This Context parameter is nothing but your Activity class's Context
{
    localContactsObj.clear();
    //localContactsName.clear();
    //localContactsNumber.clear();


    Cursor cursor =getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, "upper(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    Integer contactsCount = cursor.getCount(); // get how many contacts you have in your contacts list
    if (contactsCount > 0)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            LocalContacts  localContacts = new LocalContacts();
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                //the below cursor will give you details for multiple contacts
                Cursor pCursor = cntx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                // continue till this cursor reaches to all phone numbers which are associated with a contact in the contact list
                while (pCursor.moveToNext())
                {   //String isStarred      = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED));
                    String phoneNo  = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String phoneName    = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String photo    = pCursor.getString(pCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));

                    //localContactsName.add(contactName+"");
                    //  localContactsNumber.add(phoneNo.replaceAll("[\\s\\-\\.\\^:,]",""));

                    localContacts.name = contactName+"";
                    localContacts.number = phoneNo.replaceAll("[\\s\\-\\.\\^:,]","")+"";
                    localContacts.photo = photo;
                    localContactsObj.add(localContacts);

                }
                pCursor.close();
            }
        }

    }
    cursor.close();
}
```